# Implementing multiple queue and single thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

Using Java I need to implement the following architecture:
There are multiple queues with jobs continuously coming in the queues. There is a single thread picking up jobs from the queues following a scheduling algorithm. I should be able to write my own scheduling algorithm. 
Can you please tell me which Java API to use to implement this?
I have used ThreadPoolExecutor, but with this I could implement a single job queue and a thread pool containing multiple threads.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at all the implementations of the Queue interface in [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)? Pick your poison.

Comment: Actually I am able to implement queue. What I need is multiple queues and a single thread..

Answer (score 3):

Use multiple concurrent queues and one semaphore.  In the producers, push objects and signal the semaphore.  In the one consumer, wait on the 'common' semaphore and then poll the queues according to your scheduling algorithm - one of them must have an object on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you please tell me how to use multiple queues. I am not aware of any Java API, which will allow me to have multiple queues.

Comment: @user2110873 - there is no such API.  You need to implement this yourself as described in this Answer.